# Sharepoint 2013 Property ServerRender for New/Edit Forms Webparts

Tags: 2013, edit-form

all!

I have a problem with custom new/edit form.  In my listTemplate I set:

```
<Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" >
        <WebParts>
          <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Main" WebPartOrder="1">
            <![CDATA[
              <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
              <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>                        
              <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart</TypeName>
              <PageType>PAGE_NEWFORM</PageType>
              <CSRRenderMode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">ServerRender</CSRRenderMode>
              </WebPart>
             ]]>
          </AllUsersWebPart>
        </WebParts>
      </Form>
```

Because in other way custom validations(C# code) for field didnt work. But if it like this rendering template for new/edit form contains two web parts (I see it in SPDesigner) and as a result two toolbars(top and bottom).

Why this happen? And how fix it?

P.S. if I delete property ServerRender - new/edit form is ok, but validation didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. The problem was on one attribure called UseDefaultListFormWebPart="False".

For correct work - need to use this:

```
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" UseDefaultListFormWebPart="False">
    <WebParts>
      <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Main" WebPartOrder="1">
        <![CDATA[
          <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
          <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>                        
          <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart</TypeName>
          <PageType>PAGE_NEWFORM</PageType>
          <CSRRenderMode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">ServerRender</CSRRenderMode>
          </WebPart>
         ]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart>
    </WebParts>
  </Form>
```